# How to animate a mesh that changes through editing?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, edit-mode

So I want to change how the mesh looks (through edit mode) so the geometry of the shape changes throughout the animation. So I have a laser but I want my selected faces to be scaling up and down. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add more information as to *what* changes you want to happen.

Comment: @RayMairlot I added more infomation

Comment: shapekeys should do. Can't write a full answer for now.

Comment: @Bithur I'll look it up

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use shape keys:

1. Go into the mesh properties

[image]

2. Add a new shape key

[image]

3. add another shape key
4. Edit your mesh
5. Animate the influence of the new shape key by hovering over the property and hitting <kbd>I</kbd>

[image]

Comment: @Chickenator You can also Up vote during the wait :D

Comment: Thanks for also adding pictures. I've figured it out now ended up looking quite cool